# Can one set a border around a GaugeField?

Tags: blackberry

I'm trying to put a 1px border around a GaugeField to make it stand out.  I'm using the code below, but it isn't having any effect.

SetBorder is in the api of GaugeField, but I'm not doing something right.  Ideas?

```
    progressBar = new GaugeField(null,0,100,0,GaugeField.PERCENT);
    progressBar.setBorder(BorderFactory.createSimpleBorder(
            new XYEdges(1,1,1,1), 
            new XYEdges(0,0,0,0),
            Border.STYLE_FILLED));
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It will have affect if you change from `Border.STYLE_FILLED` to `Border.STYLE_SOLID`.

The [doc](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/6.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/ui/decor/BorderFactory.html#createSimpleBorder%28net.rim.device.api.ui.XYEdges,%20net.rim.device.api.ui.XYEdges,%20int%29) for `BorderFactory.createSimpleBorder(XYEdges edges, XYEdges colors, int style)` says:

```
style - STYLE_TRANSPARENT, STYLE_SOLID, SYLE_DOTTED, STYLE_DASHED.
```

Note there's no `Border.STYLE_FILLED` in that list.

Comment: Right in front of me!  I should have asked hours ago.  Thank you very much!

Comment: Wouldn't it be great if using an invalid style threw an error?

Comment: :) A question to RIM devs. Yes, it would.